# npm run make is not working in electron-forge

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

I have created and electron application and trying to use electron forge for building purpose.
Please find below command which i have run it for creating the electron application:

```
   #npm i -g create-react-app
   #npm i -g @electron-forge/cli
   #npx create-electron-app my-ele-app
```

The above last command created a project my-ele-app. and now i am able to start the application as well.
#npm start.

content of package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "my-ele-app",
  "productName": "my-ele-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": {
    "name": "rohit",
    "email": "rohit@xyz.com"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "my_ele_app"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.55",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.55",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.55",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.55",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.55",
    "electron": "12.0.9"
  }
}
```

Now when i am running below command, it is throwing error:

**#npm run make**

Error is:

```
> my-ele-app@1.0.0 make
> electron-forge make

√ Checking your system
√ Resolving Forge Config

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Could not find module with name: @electron-forge/maker-squirrel. Make sure it's listed in the devDependencies of your package.json
    at _default (C:\Users\212807091\Desktop\Rohit\Office Note\RBAC\Electron_project\npx_electrong\my-ele-app\node_modules\@electron-forge\core\src\api\make.ts:125:15)
    at C:\Users\212807091\Desktop\Rohit\Office Note\RBAC\Electron_project\npx_electrong\my-ele-app\node_modules\@electron-forge\cli\src\electron-forge-make.ts:44:5

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
```

NOTE: i can see there is module available in node_modules folder:
**my-ele-app\node_modules@electron-forge\maker-squirrel**

If anyone here has any idea how to fix this issue. please provide the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue but I followed the instructions from here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start#package-and-distribute-your-application

I missed calling `npx electron-forge import`. So the full pipeline looks like this:

```sh
npm install --save-dev @electron-forge/cli
npx electron-forge import
npm run make
```

Comment: I've done all the steps, but the app `npm run make` creates contains nothing, just an empty app, how could I fix that?

Answer (score 4):

In my cases, it makes error when the description or author is empty in package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after following the "Getting Started" instructions. Nothing resolved it until I ran npm install `-g @electron-forge/cli@beta` -- after that finished I was able to successfully run `electron-forge make`.
Also running npm run make did the same as electron-forge make as I didn't appear to have it installed. Another thing I noticed is that if I run npm run make with maker-squirrel at `version 6.0.0-beta.55` then I get this error: Could not find module with name: `@electron-forge/maker-squirrel`. However, if I re-install maker-squirrel as `npm install --save-dev @electron-forge/maker-squirrel@6.0.0-beta.33` and re-run `npm run make` then I get an out folder with an `exe`.

Answer (score 0):

you have installed all the required dependencies so just run this command

```
npm run package
```

And after this a folder with name `out` is generated and inside that your .exe file will be present

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Windows, this works for me:

Run `npm i electron-winstaller --save-dev --ignore-scripts`

Install *7zip x86* in your computer. After installed, go to **C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip** and copy both ***7z.dll*** and ***7z.exe*** files to **/path/to/your_project/node_modules/electron-winstaller/vendor** if they are not still there.

Run `npm electron-forge import`  again

Then try run `npm run make`  again. I hope it works.

Answer (score -1):

Check [the documentation](https://www.electronforge.io/config/makers/squirrel.windows). i solve same problem with this